# Z-indexes: Two stacked divs, both with pseudo:before that have to be behind their respective element. Not possible?

Tags: html, css, z-index, stacked

http://jsfiddle.net/qzLykrba/1/

Red box is the parent div. Blue box is the child div.
Purple box is the parent pseudo:before, that has to be behind the parent red box.
Green box is the child pseudo:before, that has to be behind the child blue box, but above the parent red box.

I can't get the parent pseudo element behind the parent div.
I know that I have to remove the parent z-index to get the parent pseudo element behind the parent, but if I do, then the childs pseudo element goes behind the parent div too.

```
.parent { 
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: red;
position: relative;

margin-left: 50px;
}

.parent:before { 
z-index: -1;
position: absolute; 
content: ""; 
bottom: -50px; 
left: -30px; 
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
background: purple; 
}

.child { 
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}

.child:before { 
z-index: -1;
position: absolute; 
content: ""; 
bottom: -50px; 
left: -30px; 
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
background: green; 
}
```

Comment: Not possible as the answer below points out, but you can [simulate it like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ntL0c5ya/) by providing a background to a child element with 100% height / width and layering that child with z-index over the pseudo elements :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible, since the pseudo elements act like children of the element they are assigned to.

```
<div class="parent">    z: 5
   :before              z: 4 // still above the parent, since it's a child of it
   <div class="child">  z: 3 // below parent:before, above parent
       :before          z: 2 // above child
       "Some text"      
       :after           z: 1 // below child:before, above child
    </div>              
   :after               z: 2 // below child, parent:before
</div>
```

Another note:

Negative values for `z-index`es are not overall supported, or don't produce the same behavior.

Comment: I think it is not possible indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want this (http://jsfiddle.net/qzLykrba/2/):

```
.parent { 
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absoulte;
    z-index:0;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.parent:before { 
    z-index: -1000;
    position: absolute; 
    content: ""; 
    bottom: -50px; 
    left: -30px; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: purple; 
}

.child { 
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

.child:before { 
    z-index: 2000;
    position: absolute; 
    content: ""; 
    bottom: -50px; 
    left: -30px; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: green; 
}
```

Comment: you have a typo on the parent div (position: absoulte;), but even if I correct his, the green box doesn't appear below the blue box.